# Seperate number and operator from String Array

Tags: swift, string

I used the code below to sperate number and operator from String elements in Array (args). This works with Arrays that have have both operator and number (like "-29")) but not for the final element like `args = ["-29", "+", "20", - , "15"]` and not with arrays having one element and the final element that contain both operators and number like args = `["-29", "+", "20", - , "-15"]` as it doesn't separate the last element. What is the problem?

```
for index in args.indices {

   if (args[index].count > 1 || index == args.endIndex + 1) {
       let first = args[index].index(args[index].startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
       let second = args[index].index(args[index].startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
   if (args[index][first] == "-" || args[index][first] == "+") && (args[index][second] >= "0" && args[index][second] <= "9") {
     if (args [index])[first] == "-"
                {
                    args[index].remove(at: first)
                    args.insert("-", at: index)
                }
                if (args [index])[first] == "+"
                {
                    args[index].remove(at: first)
                    args.insert("+", at: index)
                }
                print ("args after every check op \(args)")
                print ("args index is \(index)")
                print ("args index is \(args.endIndex)")

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide an input example and the expected result

Comment: That code is a mess anyway. There are things that make no sense, e.g. `index == args.endIndex + 1` which shouldn't happen at first glance. However, you are updating the input array during iteration, therefore almost anything can happen.

Answer (score 2):

The most problematic part is that you are trying to modify the array that is being iterated, therefore changing its indices during iteration. For example, when you are iterating over indices `0...5`, after first number with a sign, your array will actually have indices `0...6` and the last item won't be ever reached by the iteration.

There are some simple workarounds, e.g. using a manual `while` loop, or just iterating from the end:

```
for index in args.indices.reversed() {
```

However, the best solution is to create a whole new array instead of modifying the input array. Also, the code could be greatly simplified:

```
let args = ["-29", "+", "20", "-" , "-15"]
var output: [String] = []
for arg in args {
    // if the arg is not a sign followed by a number, push it directly to output
    guard arg.range(of: "^[+-]\\d+$", options: .regularExpression) != nil else {
        output.append(arg)
        continue
    }

    // split arg to sign and number and push them to output
    let secondIndex = arg.index(arg.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
    let sign = String(arg[arg.startIndex])
    let number = String(arg[secondIndex...])
    output.append(sign)
    output.append(number)
}

print(output) // ["-", "29", "+", "20", "-", "-", "15"]
```